# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query summary/stats, row count?

Tags: mysql

I have been looking everywhere but it looks like I need to add a new question;

I am loading a csv file using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...`  and am trying to get number of inserted rows - my first guess was to use: `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` but that returns 0.

I can see Mysql knows the number of affected rows and execution time since it prints that after the statement is executed;

```
Query OK, 20897 rows affected (0.87 sec)
Records: 20897  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Question: Is there any way I could select that into variable and use it in another statement?**

I'm thinking something like: `SELECT VARIABLES LIKE 'rows_affected' INTO varname;` (*obviously this statement is invalid*)

I was looking at performance schema and sessions variable but without any luck.

My console dump:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.6.44 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> TRUNCATE database.table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'some_file.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE database.table
    -> CHARACTER SET 'latin1' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
    -> (@A,@B)
    -> SET 
    -> col1=@A,
    -> col2=@B;
Query OK, 20897 rows affected (0.87 sec)
Records: 20897  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the row count in MySQL or another language (php, etc...)?

Comment: @Jason I know how to get that in PHP I want to do it in mysql. The goal is to SELECT the row count into Mysql variable and use it in another statement.

Comment: Retrieve destination table's rows count before and after.

Comment: @Akina I know I could do this `SELECT table_rows FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'` or simply run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database.table` but first is not accurate and second is slow.
This is two extra queries I don't have to run as the engine already did the job of counting the new records - this is waste of time and CPU and I thought there is a simple way of getting that info.